# Strange beamer problem

Tags: math-mode, beamer

Could anybody tell me why the following `beamer` document does not compile?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\let\mathbb\undefined
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\mathbb{Q}$
\pause
\begin{itemize}
 \item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The strange thing is that the code compiles when I remove *either one* of the following:

1. the first `\DeclareMathAlphabet`,
2. `\let\mathbb\undefined`,
3. `$\mathbb{Q}$`
4. `\pause`,
5. the `itemize` environment.

Of course, the first two lines in this document are superfluous, but I would like to know what is going wrong.

I am using `beamer` in version 3.10 with TeXLive 2011.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error has surely to do with **beamer**'s internal working when trying to split material for the overlays. I've not followed the error, but I have some suspects:

1. the `\let\mathbb\undefined` makes LaTeX follow a different branch in a conditional than when it finds the command defined;
2. math alphabets are evaluated only when needed, because of the strong limitation to 16 math families (this explains why omitting `\mathbb{Q}` doesn't trigger the error);
3. the error doesn't show without `\pause` because there's no "delayed expansion" (similar when TeX is writing out an auxiliary file).

You get the same error with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\let\mathbb\undefined
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A $\mathbb{Q}$}
\end{document}
```

but not at the first run: only at the second, when the `.toc` file is read in, the error shows.

Running the second example twice and skipping past errors with return, the

```
! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.
```

error message will show. This means that LaTeX is chasing its tail defining over and over again the same math alphabet. It does not happen if the `\let\mathbb\undefined` is omitted because it's legal to reassign a math alphabet selection command. When it's inserted, the system is in an unstable state, because `\mathbb` has no meaning, while `\csname mathbb \endcsname` has the old meaning (this has to do with "command robusting"). In the code for `\DeclareMathAlphabet` there's a conditional which depends on the first one being defined or not. If it's not, the second one is appended to the list of math alphabets to initialize, and I believe it's here that things go wrong: LaTeX finds the same command twice in the list `\mv@normal` that expands to

```
\getanddefine@fonts \symoperators \OT1/cmr/m/n
\getanddefine@fonts \symletters \OML/cmm/m/it
\getanddefine@fonts \symsymbols \OMS/cmsy/m/n
\getanddefine@fonts \symlargesymbols \OMX/cmex/m/n
\install@mathalphabet \mathbf  {\select@group \mathbf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/bx/n }
\install@mathalphabet \mathsf  {\select@group \mathsf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmss/m/n }
\install@mathalphabet \mathit  {\select@group \mathit  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/m/it }
\install@mathalphabet \mathtt  {\select@group \mathtt  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmtt/m/n }
\install@mathalphabet \mathbb  {\select@group \mathbb  \M@U \U/msb/m/n }
\install@mathalphabet \mathbb  {\select@group \mathbb  \M@U \U/msb/m/n }
```

(end-of-lines have been added for clarity). It's clearly visible that `\mathbb`  (with a space in the name) appears twice. I don't understand precisely why this becomes a problem when typesetting the table of contents (or storing in memory the frame with `\pause` in **beamer**), but it obviously has to do with this duplication.

It's always risky to say `\let\xyz\undefined` when `\xyz` is defined by `\DeclareRobustCommand` or another command that performs a similar task and then redefining `\xyz`.

Comment: Thanks. I would be glad if you could explain further why the first three commands after `\documentclass` are not equivalent to a single call to `\DeclareMathAlphabet`?

Comment: @Michael Here is further analysis.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that e.g. the `eufrak` package uses `\newcommand` to define `\mathfrak`, and then `\DeclareMathAlphabet` gives an error when `\mathfrak` is not set to undefined before.

Comment: Yes: `\DeclareMathAlphabet` can know whether the command is already defined as a math alphabet choice command; otherwise it raises the error, since it assumes you are trying to redefine a command, while reassigning a math alphabet is quite common. Actually **eufrak** is kind of obsolete, since **amsfonts** is richer; however it seems a bad design decision to use `\newcommand` instead of `\DeclareMathAlphabet`.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `\DeclareMathAlphabet` instead of `\usepackage{amssymb}`?
The following appears to work fine, as far as I can tell:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern} % To avoid ``LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in
                     % size <4> not available'' warnings
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\mathbb{Q}$
\pause
\begin{itemize}
 \item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I said, the error also does not occur if I remove the first `\DeclareMathAlphabet` statement. I just want to know why there is an error.

Comment: Right, I was just wondering why you went that route at all -- the amsmath and related documentation *normally* never mentions it at all, and just says to use amssymb, which appears to be either inherently more robust than `\DeclareMathAlphabet`, or beamer takes extra effort to accommodate it.

Comment: The error occurred for me because I included two packages that both redefine one of the alphabets. BTW, if I look into `amsfonts.sty` (which is included by `amssymb.sty`), it seems it just uses `\DeclareMathAlphabet` and the related `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet` itself to set up the math alphabets.

Comment: I thought it could be something like that, but wanted to make sure. I suppose the packages could check if the proper math alphabets were already set, or else use a different command to clear or redefine the math alphabet, similar to what @egreg mentioned earlier.